# Talend file mask with regular expression

Tags: regex, talend

I try to read a file (with ftpGet) with a name like this: TRE.DSF.20140903.01.TXT

I put this in my file mask: "TRE.DSF.[0-9]{6}.[0-9]{2}.TXT"

But it doesn't work. I tried many other thing, but I can't figure out how the "regexp talend" works...

Answer (score 1):

There are 8 digits in the first number. But your regex `[0-9]{6}` matches only 6. The remaining 2 is not matched and it causes the whole regex to fail.

```
"TRE\\.DSF\\.[0-9]{8}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.TXT"
```

Comment: Just as a note, Talend is a java code  generator so backslashes need to be escaped as well since it will thrown an error or also won't work

Comment: I read that talend replace . with '\.' and * with '.*'. Tried with "TRE.DSF.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.TXT" and "TRE.DSF.[0-9]{8}.[0-9]{2}.TXT" but it doesn't work

Comment: try `"^TRE\\.DSF\\.[0-9]{8}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.TXT$"`